# how to put product label on mysql product list

Tags: php, mysql, label, product

I have a product list page and I am trying to figure out how to put product label on selected items. I have a category $bestseller and I want them to have a best seller image label on its upper right corner.

Any help? Thanks.

```
<?php
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 15");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
$i = 0;

$dynamicList = '<table  border="1" bordercolor="#d6d6d6" cellpadding="10"         
cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
     $id = $row["id"];
     $brand = $row["brand"];
     $product_name = $row["product_name"];
     $pdetails = $row["pdetails"];
     $bestseller = $row["bestseller"];
     $details = $row["details"];
     $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
     if ($i % 3 == 0) { // if $i is divisible by our target number (in 
this case "3")
         $dynamicList .= '<tr><td><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '" 
title="' . $pdetails . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="295" 
border="0" ><br><br>' . $brand . '<br>' . $product_name . '</a></td>';
    } else {

                $dynamicList .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '" title="' . 
$pdetails . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="295" border="0" >
<br><br>' . $brand . '<br>' . $product_name . '</a></td>';
    }
    $i++;
}
$dynamicList .= '</tr></table>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>

<title>Product List</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.png" />
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png" type="image/x-icon" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../rustansstyle.css" />

</head>

<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0"         
bottommargin="0">
<center>
<div id="mainWrapper">
<?php include_once("header.php");?>

<div id="pagetitle_skincare" style="margin-top:0px;"></div>
<table border="0">
        <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="230">
    <div id="product_category">
        <li><a href="#">Dresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short Dresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Maxi Dresses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cocktail Dresses</a></li>

    </div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="950">
    <div class="preview_inner"><?php echo $dynamicList; ?></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br /><?php include_once("footer.php");?>
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: So u want something like if $bestseller == 1 the include image?

Comment: @bart2puck I have 3 categories. Best seller, top rated, and None. If $category = best seller, I want them to have a label image on upper right corner of its box.

Right now, <?php echo $dynamicList; ?> shows all products, best seller or not.

I like this example with Free Shipping label on the item: http://www.opencart.com/opencart/image/cache/data/extension/1307179625.product_pl-500x500.jpg

in my case, it should be best seller.